# How to put a very long table layout inside the horizontal Scroll view in the CORRECT way?

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, android-tablelayout

I tried looking at numerious examples and posts but none of them matches my problem.

I need to make a very long (horizontal) table with many columns so it is impossible to display in a single screen. And I don't want to spilt the table because it is important that I display my table in this way.

I have pasted my XML layout below (including the main important ones)

The thing is if I remove the code:

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

from the **HorizontalScrollView** then my table inside it, gets squeezed in one place, especially at the left side of it. It doesn't even use much of this HorizontalScrollView container area.

And,
If I use this code, then this HorizontalScrollView shows my whole table inside it - the columns are squeeze to make sure they fit in this scrollview.

**I just want this scrollview to display only the content of my tablelayout that fits in the screen width, so I can scroll the remaining columns.** But right now, I don't seem to get anywhere near.

So how do I solve my problem? Am I doing something wrong ?

Also here is my XML layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/bot_scoreBoard"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/table_shape"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="*" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            >
            <TextView
            />
               ....
            more than 16 columns of made using TextView
 ....
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer. It was because I was using the

```
 android:stretchColumns="*"
```

in the TableLayout.

Plus my TextView which were the columns, needed to some specific width size rather than just

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" or "wrap_content"
```

Those were the problems.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your `TableLayout` with a `LinearLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/bot_scoreBoard"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/table_shape"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#ffffff" >

                <TextView />
           ....
        more than 16 columns of made using TextView
     ....
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: I not sure how that would help. I tried it and it still isn't doing what I want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `android:stretchColumns="*"` you have to use some definite value with your `layout_width` instead of `match_parent` and `wrap_content`.

for ex. `layout_width = "250dp"`